# Gráfico em barras gerado com Python ficou ilegível. Como melhorá-lo? Como trabalhar com um dataset de mais de 1 milhão de linhas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Amigos,

O seguinte gráfico em barra foi gerado (a primeira coluna dos datasets é UNIX time):

[image: Gráfico ilegível]

O código Python (versão 3.5) usado foi o seguinte:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []
with open("/Radhe/LabAbril2017Capturas/slices_calculos/winTime_10Abril_SemAtaques.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        X,Y = l.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append(float(X))
        y.append(float (Y))

x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
y_pos = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(y)]

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

y1 = []
v = 0
y_sorted = sorted(y)
for i in y_sorted:
    if(abs(i-v > 50)):
        y1.append(i)
        v = i

plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='edge', color="blue", alpha=0.5, width=0.5) 

plt.title("Tamanho da janela TCP durante período sem ataques")
plt.ylabel("Tamanho da janela TCP")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x1, size='small',rotation=35, ha="right")
plt.yticks(y1)
plt.ylim(ymin=y_sorted[0]-200) # valor minimo do eixo y

plt.show()
```

Usando o dataset winTime_10Abril_slowloris.csv, o gráfico também ficou ruim:

[image: usando winTime_10Abril_slowloris.csv]

O dataset winTime_10Abril_SemAtaques.csv está disponível aqui:
https://ufile.io/l2ejn

O dataset winTime_10Abril_slowloris.csv está disponível aqui:
https://ufile.io/8mbc0

Como tornar o gráfico mais legível?
Alguma forma mais eficiente de fazer? O meu próximo dataset tem cerca de 1 milhão de linhas.... Vai demorar muito...

Dataset de 1 milhão de linhas (winTime_10Abril_sockstress.csv): https://ufile.io/qolsg

Comment: Uma solução razoavelmente simples para os labels é fazer um if multiplo de 10 (ou outro valor) escreve o label, assim ao menos vai ficar legível

Comment: @Bacco: não entendi muito bem. Poderia exemplificar ou escrever uma resposta por favor?

Comment: @Bacco: e o programa está muito lento. Tentei rodar no dataset com mais de 1 milhão de linhas e numa máquina com 16 GB RAM tem mais de uma hora rodando e nada... E está usando 99,9% de RAM...

Comment: Pergunta difícil. Quando se tem essa quantidade de dados (que nem é tão absurda, mas já fica difícil visualizar por item), o ideal é usar métodos de agrupamento ou estatísticas gerais. Ou seja, o gráfico de barras não é apropriado para plotar *cada um dos itens*. Se você não quiser plotar médias ou algo do tipo no lugar, dá uma olhada nos gráficos do pacote [Seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/).

Comment: Ah, e sobre grandes datasets, o seu melhor amigo é o [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Meio resposta, meio comentário.

Dê uma olhada nesta pergunta/resposta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855794/plotting-too-many-lines-in-matplotlib-out-of-memory

Ela é baseada no uso da capacidade [`Line Collection`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/line_collection2.html) do matplotlib.

Talvez vc consiga usar a mesma técnica. Uma outra opcão é reduzir o numero de linhas e pontos como foi sugerido. Em geral vc não precisa de 1 milhão de pontos, vc  precisa de 1000 pontos. A parte difícil é selecionar e colocar apenas o que é necessário (por exemplo, só alguns `ticks` pra reduzir a parte gráfica já ajudam).

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: @Guto: o outro problema é o gráfico ter ficado ilegível. Conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: Dei uma editada na resposta, um pouco mais clara agora. Vou manter isso em mente, mesmo que o link original seja perfeito.